# Colly - How to get the value of a child attribute?

Tags: go, go-colly

Here is the sample page I been working on `https://www.lazada.vn/-i1701980654-s7563711492.html`

Here is the element I want to get (the product title)

```
...
<div>
   <img src="https://lzd-img-global.slatic.net/g/tps/imgextra/i1/O1CN01JUOYif22N3Uu7JX4R_!!6000000007107-2-tps-162-48.png" class="pdp-mod-product-badge" alt="LazMall">
    <h1 class="pdp-mod-product-badge-title">
     Yierku 【Free Shipping Miễn phí vận chuyển】Giày nam mùa thu và mùa đông giày thường xu hướng nam thể thao tất cả các trận đấu giày da tăng chiều cao giày nam
    </h1>
</div>
...
```

I want to get the text value between the `<h1>` element which is `Yierku 【Free Shipping Miễn phí vận chuyển】Giày n....`

Here is what I have tried so far

```
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    c.OnError(func(_ *colly.Response, err error) {
        log.Println("Something went wrong:", err)
    })
    c.OnXML("/html/body", func(e *colly.XMLElement) {
        child := e.ChildAttrs("div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/h1", "class")
        fmt.Println(child)
        //fmt.Println(child)
    })
```

It gives the response of `pdp-mod-product-badge-title`

When I tried to change it into

`child := e.ChildAttrs("div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/h1", "text")`

It does not give me any result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [func (*XMLElement) ChildText](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gocolly/colly/v2#XMLElement.ChildText) instead.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gocolly/colly/v2"
)

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector()
    c.OnError(func(_ *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong:", err)
    })
    c.OnXML("/html/body", func(e *colly.XMLElement) {
        child := e.ChildText("div[4]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/h1")
        fmt.Println(child)
    })
    c.Visit("https://www.lazada.vn/-i1701980654-s7563711492.html")
    // Output:
    // Yierku 【Free Shipping Miễn phí vận chuyển】Giày nam mùa thu và mùa đông giày thường xu hướng nam thể thao tất cả các trận đấu giày da tăng chiều cao giày nam
}
```